# Rendering HAML from Rails Helper Inside a Loop/Iteration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, helper

I have the following code inside a helper in rails:

```
def custom_options_tag(opts={})
  ['am', 'pm'].each do |meridian|
    ["12", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11"].each do |time|
      if @event.send(opts[:method], opts[:arg]) == time.to_s + meridian
        engine = Haml::Engine.new("%option{:value => human_time, :selected => 'selected'}= human_time")
      else
        engine = Haml::Engine.new("%option{:value => human_time}= human_time")
      end
      engine.render(Object.new, :human_time => time.to_s + meridian)
    end
  end
end
```

My question is...
How can this code be rendered in my view?
It seems there is no way to render haml code that has gone through a loop inside a helper method.

To simplify things I've tried to render a paragraph 3 times...

```
def some_paragraph_helper
  3.times do
    engine = Haml::Engine.new("%p Some paragraph from helper")
    engine.render
  end
end
```

When I call the method...

```
some_paragraph_helper
```

...it outputs not the text but simply the number "3" without the paragraph tag. Note that it only shows the number "3" once... as if it was not going through the loop.

Thanks for helping.

LP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to return result of `engine.render`

```
def some_paragraph_helper
  result = ""
  3.times do
    engine = Haml::Engine.new("%p Some paragraph from helper")
    result << engine.render
  end
  result
end
```

Comment: if you don't want escapes return `raw(result)`

Comment: Works well! Thx... Why do I need to explicitly return the result value and not escape it? Usually I don't need to do so if I'm not using a loop.